# How does bootstrap.js gray out a background

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to debug a legacy web application that uses bootstrap.js to raise a modal and gray out the page underneath. Warning, I am NOT a JS/HTML/CCS dev, but apparently this is mine now.

The code working properly depending on the iframe. When the iframe consists of standard html, it seems to work fine. When the iframe consists of this strange sort-of HTML produced by WebFocus (that only renders properly in IE).

Anyway, when the modal opens, the following changes are made to the DOM:

This div tag is added to the body element:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

The associated styles are these:

```
/*media all*/
.in.modal-backdrop {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: 0.5;
}


/*media all*/
.fade.modal-backdrop {
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Also, the open-modal style is applied to the body element like so:

```
<body class="modal-open">
```

With the associated style:

```
/*media all*/
.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Now I would expect that the modal-backdrop style to have to apply to something other than an empty div tag for it to work. How does that work? Why would it work when applied to one type of iframe but not another.

The iframe is as follows:

```
<iframe name="Report Content" width="100%" height="400" title="Webfocus HTML Report" id="htmlReportFrame" src="/path/to/webfocus/report?reportParam=123456" onreadystatechange="readyStateChange()" onload="return readyStateChange();">Your
            browser does not support IFRAMES</iframe>
```

The report reference by the iframe (/path/to/webfocus/report?reportParam=123456) returns this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Figure 1</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
@media screen {
 .spacer { height:792pt; }
}
@media print {
 .spacer { height:792pt; }
}
.x1 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:7pt;
 color:#000000;
 }
.x2 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:9pt;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#000000;
 }
.x3 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:9pt;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#000000;
 text-align:left;
 }
.x4 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:7pt;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#000000;
 text-align:center;
 }
.x5 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:7pt;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#000000;
 }
.x6 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:7pt;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#000000;
 }
.x7 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:7pt;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#000000;
 }
.x8 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Courier New;
 font-size:12pt;
 }
.x9 {
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-family:Courier New;
 font-size:12pt;
 }
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:relative" class="spacer">
<div style="position:absolute;top:216pt;left:104pt;width:434pt;height:1pt;background-color:#000000;
border-top:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-bottom:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-left:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-right:#000000 1.00pt solid;
 font-size:1pt"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:237pt;left:104pt;width:432pt;height:1pt;background-color:#000000;
border-top:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-bottom:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-left:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-right:#000000 1.00pt solid;
 font-size:1pt"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:218pt;left:104pt;width:1pt;height:21pt;background-color:#000000;
border-top:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-bottom:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-left:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-right:#000000 1.00pt solid;
"></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:218pt;left:536pt;width:1pt;height:21pt;background-color:#000000;
border-top:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-bottom:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-left:#000000 1.00pt solid;
border-right:#000000 1.00pt solid;
"></div>
<IMG SRC="file:///C:/orange_purple25x12.gif" style='position:absolute;left:108pt;top:222pt;width=25pt;height=12pt;' >
<IMG SRC="file:///C:/blueline5025x12.gif" style='position:absolute;left:252pt;top:222pt;width=25pt;height=12pt;' >
<IMG SRC="file:///C:/yellowlavender25x12.gif" style='position:absolute;left:396pt;top:222pt;width=25pt;height=12pt;' >
<div style="position:absolute;top:221pt;left:136pt; text-align:left;">
<span class='x5'>Category 1</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:221pt;left:280pt; text-align:left;">
<span class='x6'>Category 2</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:221pt;left:424pt; text-align:left;">
<span class='x7'>Category 3</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:0pt;left:36pt; text-align:left;">
<span class='x2'>&nbsp;</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:11pt;left:36pt; text-align:left;">
<span class='x3'>Figure Name</span></div>
<div style="position:absolute;top:23pt;left:297pt; text-align:left;">
<span class='x4'>United</span></div>
<IMG SRC="file:///C:/IBIUniqueName0.png" style='position:absolute;left:36pt;top:33pt;' >
<div style="position:absolute;top:28pt;left:36pt; text-align:left;">
<span class='x8'>&nbsp;</span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It looks like standard html, except that it reference local image files (for example file:///C:/IBIUniqueName0.png) that don't exist. I believe that they are being delivered to the browser using some sort of strange mime type, but I don't know how.

I can post more code, but I need to remove sensitive information.

Comment: It can be empty because it's just a `fixed` positioned element that is 100% width and height so that it covers the rest of the content. It also acts as a click target for closing the modal. As for the iFrame issue, we would need to see the issue recreated to advise you on that.

Comment: What is the bahavior you are getting? Does the backdrop not display, is it behind the iframe but not covering it, etc?

Comment: From what I can tell, the backdrop is behind the iframe, but in front of the rest of the page. Then when the modal opens, the backdrop opacity increases to 0.5 graying out the page, but not the iframe.